# How to change post date language from English to French in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show the date in the posts in French language, more specifically just the month. For eg. January should appear as Janvier and so on.

For eg. if the post date is 30 APRIL 2015 it should appear as 30 AVRIL 2015

Is there a workaround for this, any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So you don't want everything to be in french (using wordpress localization) but only timestamp, then you'll most probably have to edit one wp-*.php. I suggest adding at the very end of wp-load.php :

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fra_fra');
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, if we're showing posts on the homepage, can we also translate 'shares' in French? I want to replace Shares with Partages